# How can i remove duplicate key and value from multiple array

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have a multiple array function and need to remove duplicate value from the array in view and show in the list.

array trying to remove "mfgg_name" if comes more than 1 time

```
array:44 [▼
 0 => array:4 [▼
   "mfgg_name" => "Solomon Colors, Inc."
   "mfgg_id" => 122
   "product_name" => "Lythic Protector"
   "product_id" => 2586
 ]
 1 => array:4 [▼
   "mfgg_name" => "Solomon Colors, Inc."
   "mfgg_id" => 122
   "product_name" => "Lythic SPD Protector"
   "product_id" => 2587
 ]
 2 => array:4 [▼
   "mfgg_name" => "Solomon Colors, Inc."
   "mfgg_id" => 122
   "product_name" => "Lythic Cleaner"
   "product_id" => 2588
 ]
 3 => array:4 [▼
   "mfgg_name" => "Solomon Colors, Inc."
   "mfgg_id" => 122
   "product_name" => "Lythic DAY1 Hardener"
   "product_id" => 2589
 ]
```

```
     @if(count($list_all_active_manufacturers) > 0 ) 

                                 {{dd($list_all_active_manufacturers)}}
                                    @foreach($list_all_active_manufacturers as $leedsManufacturer)
                                <div class="post" id="post{{$leedsManufacturer['mfgg_id']}}">
                                    <label class=" my-checkbox gry2" id="manufacturer">{{str_limit($leedsManufacturer['mfgg_name'], 300)}}
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="manufacturer common_selector" name="manufacturer[]" value="{{$leedsManufacturer['mfgg_id']}}">
                                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                                    @endforeach 
                                @endif
```

Comment: wHAT IS YOUr expected output?

Comment: How did you generate that array?

Comment: i want to remove duplicated `mfgg_name` value from arrays and show only one time

Comment: i generated this array from data i have multiple products and each product have its manufacturer but i need to show manufacturer only one time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function,

```
function unique_multidim_array($array, $key)
{
    $temp_array = [];
    $i          = 0;
    $key_array  = [];
    foreach ($array as $val) {
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) {
            $key_array[$i]  = $val[$key];
            $temp_array[$i] = $val;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $temp_array;
}
// unique by mfgg_name
$result = unique_multidim_array($yourArr,'mfgg_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

there are probably better anyswers out there, but this is what I would do based on the quality of the data -

```
foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
    unset($test[$key + 1]['mfgg_name']);
}
```

what this does is it keeps the name is the first array, but removes it for all arrays afterwards - then I would do a `isset()` to check whether is exists on the output

```
@if(count($list_all_active_manufacturers) > 0 ) 
    @foreach($list_all_active_manufacturers as $leedsManufacturer)
        <div class="post" id="post{{$leedsManufacturer['mfgg_id']}}">
            @if(isset($leedsManufacturer['mfgg_id]))
                <label class=" my-checkbox gry2" id="manufacturer">{{str_limit($leedsManufacturer['mfgg_name'], 300)}}
                <input type="checkbox" class="manufacturer common_selector" name="manufacturer[]" value="{{$leedsManufacturer['mfgg_id']}}">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            @endif
        </div>
     @endforeach 
@endif
```

this is untested, but might get you on the right track - if `isset()` doesn't work you could try `($leedsManufacturer['mfgg_name'] > 0)` or `@if(array_key_exists('mfgg_name', $leedsManufacturer)`